# How to use private imports in Vue styles?

Tags: css, vue.js

When I import my css file between style tags, it changes everything.

Why it is happening? How can I fix this problem?
I already used 'scoped 'feature but it is not working.

for instance

// in styles.css file

`h1 { color: red; }`

// in component file

```
<template> ... </template>
<script> ... </script>
<style scoped>
import './styles.css';
<style>
```

When I run server, it changes every *h1* tags in project. I am using '*scoped*' how can it happen.

Comment: `it changes every h1 tags`. Where are those `h1` tags? The `h1`s within the component and its children are all within scope.

Comment: Every h1 elements in project.

Answer (score 0):

Try with SCSS instead of CSS:

```js
<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import './styles.css';
</script>
```

Comment: I tried on Vue.js 3 before posting and it worked.
Try to rename the .css to .scss